# How to rollback to previous successful maven deploy on failure of curent build or deployment in jenkins Freestyle project automatically?

Tags: maven, jenkins, next.js, build, rollback

I have some Freestyle projects in Jenkins v2.401.1 and here I am getting a new challenge to rollback to previous successful build and deployment in case of the current build or deployment failure. I have no idea about the pipeline scripts. Below are the configuration of a freestyle project:

```
GENERAL:
    Discard Old Builds: Checked
    Strategy: Log Rotation
    Days to Keep Builds: 7
    Max # of builds to keep: 3
    Github Project: Checked
        Project URL: https://github.com/****/****.git/
    Restrict Where this project can be run: Checked
        Label Expression: <node name>

Source Code Management:
    Git: Checked
        Repository URL: same as project URL i. e. https://github.com/****/****.git/
        Credentials: Selected correct option from the drop down.
    Branches to Build: *

Build Triggers:
    GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling: Checked

Build Environment:
    Delete workspace before build starts: Checked
    Add timestamps to the Console Output: Checked
    Prepare SonarQube Scanner environment: Checked

Build Steps:
    Invoke top-level Maven targets:
        Maven Version: Default
        Goal: install
```

Tried to install the plugin Copy Artifacts but I did not understand how to use it.

And expecting to have the solution in Freestyle method itself.